# What items should not be kept in new home before house warming?

Tags: rituals

Are there any rules to be followed before doing house warming in new house?

I heard that no god photos should be kept inside before house warming, are there any restrictions on keeping cloths, iron, gold, sand, bricks, soaps, broom, wood etc., inside the house?

Is it okay to do bath in new house before doing house warming?